# html not displayed when I copied from jsFiddle

Tags: html, editor, jsfiddle

I have been working on jsFiddle , and I have a script and a short html.. I am able to see the output of it but when I copy the whole thing to notepad++ or any other editor such as sublime text and save as html the outout not displayed.. I have canvas on my project and when I debug it in browser(in developer tools) the canvas can be seen but it is not displayed on the page what can be the reason for that it is so weird and take my hours please help..

here is html

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Clear" />
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Generate" />
```

and here is the link with complete script hmtl and output
http://jsfiddle.net/dQppK/402/

Comment: Ok, this might be a dumb question, but are you wrapping your js in `<script></script>` and putting it into the `<head>` section of your html, or are you just pasting all of this directly into the editor and saving it as-is? It's not legit html if you're just copying and pasting it.

Comment: of course i put between script tags and so head too

Comment: Here is the answer for who experienced same issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372378/jquery-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-html?rq=1